# Finding when a particular video was last viewed on a Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, video, macbook-pro, timestamp

Me and my little brother just got a speeding fine on a trip we both take, but we're not sure who was driving. I know my little brother's been watching a particular series of videos on his Macbook Pro when I drive, and he probably hasn't watched them again.

*Is there a way to find when a particular video stored on a computer (in particular a Macbook pro) was last viewed?*

If so then we can look through and see if he was watching anything at the time of the fine.

Thanks!

Comment: were you with him at the time of the fine? was he alone and you suspect someone else was with him driving? do you want to know if it was him driving at the time of the fine or you, while both inside the car? im confused. but answering your question: `ls -lut` lists the files on your current folder by access date.

Comment: That's what we want to establish. We can't see who was in the car, but if he was watching videos then I was driving, and if he wasn't watching videos then odds are he was driving :)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the manual for `ls` :

```
NAME
     ls -- list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
     ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUW@abcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

  -l      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  If the output is to a ter-minal, terminal,
             minal, a total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long listing.

  -u      Use time of last access, instead of last modification of the file for sorting (-t) or long
             printing (-l).


     -t      Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before sorting the operands by lexico-graphical lexicographical
             graphical order.
```

That said, `ls -lut` will do the job for you.

[Manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm looking for! I'm not particularly techie I fear, so do I access this just from a 'command prompt' or some OS equivalent? Thanks

Comment: To open Terminal, navigate to your Applications folder, open Utilities, and double click on Terminal.